# Restrict REST API to Mobile App Only - Proposed Method

Tags: rest, api, security, authentication, key

I read a lot that you can't restrict your Public REST API to only your mobile application, but I have an idea and I want opinions on it:

**Variable App Key Method**

**Mobile App**

1. Get IP address of current connection
2. Use a secret algorithm to generate a hashed AppKey from IP address.
3. Send the AppKey with each API request

**Server Side**

1. Check the IP address of incoming request
2. Generate AuthKey from that IP address using same secret algorithm.
3. Compare AuthKey with AppKey, if they match then you know that your
   Application is talking to you, because only the application knows
   the secret algorithm.

**When IP address changes:**

- On mobile App regenerate the AppKey using the new IP address
- Server side will always generate same key because it depends
  on IP address of the request

The main advantage of this is that the AppKey will always change, which is better than hardcoding 1 application key inside the code, which can be easily stolen by reading request headers. And even if you stole the AppKey from a user you must be using the same IP address where that key was generated.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The "secret" algorithm would have to be in the app... given to everybody. It is not secret at all. Security by obscurity is bad anyway, you should not have supposedly secret algorithms, because it's hopeless to keep them confidential. In this case the algorithm is trivially revealed.

Also refer to Schneier's law. :)

Edit:

So theoretically, this can never be secure, because any algorithm you put into the app needs to run on the client, and hence can be analysed and decompiled. But one can argue that it doesn't need to be theoretically secure, it is ok if it's "secure enough", ie. the risk is low enough, because for example the effort needed to get to the algorithm is too much.

But then consider the two possible options:

- This is a really cool API that everybody totally wants to build a client for, or there is at least one such party. In this case, no effort is too much, and the algorithm will be "broken", that is, it will be decompiled and implemented in a different client.
- People don't care all that much about this API, it is not very important for anybody else to build a client. In this case they probably won't build a client anyway, and much simpler methods can be used to prevent other clients from popping up with a reasonable success.

But obviously, it's your choice, an approach similar to what you describied does raise the bar somewhat - just don't expect it to be actually secure, because it will not be.

Comment: Is it that easy to decompile the code? What about making the secret algorithm in compiled C++ code and integrate it with Java App? It will be much harder to decompile

Comment: @DeepBlue I extended my answer.